# Theos will not build project with the iOS 5 toolchain I've compiled

Tags: iphone, linux, makefile, toolchain

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and this is my first attempt to create an iPhone application, unless you count Flash CS5 as a platform for app development.

I've compiled an iOS 5.0 toolchain using saurik's guide at http://www.saurik.com/id/4 (and google to clarify instructions such as where to find an iPhone filesystem and SDK).

I've made a symbolic link with the name sysroot in /opt/iphone-sdk-3.0 to /dat/sys (the location of my toolchain) so theos can locate the toolchain. There doesn't seem to be much documentation on theos and it seems to only accept /opt/iphone-sdk-3.0 for the toolchain location and not something like /opt/iphone-sdk-5.0, I am not sure whether or not this may be a contributing factor to my problem.

Well, whenever I try to make my project I receive the following output;

```
Bootstrapping CydiaSubstrate...
Compiling iPhoneOS CydiaSubstrate stub... default target? failed, forcing 2.0? failed, forcing 3.0? failed, forcing 3.2? failed, forcing 4.0 for 3.0? failed, forcing 4.2 for 3.0? failed, forcing 4.0? failed, forcing 4.2? failed, what?
I didn't actually end up with a file here... I should probably bail out.
make: *** [before-all] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am receiving this error or what it means? Do the version numbers stand for iOS, XCode, LLVM... etc.

Comment: can you share your binary here.